# Overriding React's internal `type`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am wrapping a component using `styled-components`, and passing it to a 3rd party component that enforces the children you can pass by doing a type check.

```
    return React.Children.map(el.props.children, child => {
      if (child && (child.type === Fragment || child.type === MenuItemInputGroup)) {
        const children = this._renderChildren(child);
        return React.cloneElement(child, null, children);
      } else if (elementMatchesType(child, MenuItem)) {
        return this._renderMenuItem(child);
      } else {
        return child;
      }
    });
```

When you use `styled-components`, the `type` is overwritten, so this `if()` check always falls through to the final `else`.

Is it possible to fake the type back to the *wrapped* component, not the *wrapping* styled-components component?